# Trim after a split of a string on BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to trim my SYMB variable which is a simple string such as `John` or `Lucy`. There is usually some extra space and I would like to remove those extra spaces using `TRIM` inside a `WITH AS` clause

```
WITH students AS (
    SELECT 
    AZE,
    EPI,
    SYMB,
    from schools.boston, 
    unnest(split(AZE, ',') || split(EPI, ',')) as SYMB)
```

**example input data**

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "AZE": "english , chinese , french",
  "EPI": "math, physics"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "AZE": "",
  "EPI": "computer science"
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "AZE": "taiwanese, russian, italian, turkish",
  "EPI": "painting, drawing"
}
```

**output SYMB rows**

```
id 1 - row 1:english 
id 1 - row 2: chinese --> extra space to remove
id 1 - row 3: french  --> extra space to remove
id 1 - row 4:math 
id 1 - row 5: physics --> extra space to remove
```

The only location where I was able to use trim in my query was in the `SELECT` but it is only doing the `TRIM` before the split process. What would be the best way to apply a `TRIM` to my `SYMB` variable?

```
 WITH students AS (
        SELECT 
        trim(AZE) as AZE,
        trim(EPI) as EPI,
        SYMB,
        from schools.boston, 
        unnest(split(AZE, ',') || split(EPI, ',')) as SYMB)
```

Comment: Can you provide some exemplar data

Comment: I just added one example, I hope it is making sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with data as (
    select 1 as id, 'english, chinese, french' as AZE, "math, physics" as EPI   union all 
    select 2, "", "computer science"    union all 
    select 3, "taiwanese, russian, italian, turkish", "painting, drawing"
),
split_and_concat as (
    select 
        data.*, split(AZE, ',') || split(EPI, ',') as SYMB
    from data
),
trimmed as (
    select
        split_and_concat.*, trim(item) as item
    from split_and_concat,
    unnest(SYMB) as item
)
select id, item
from trimmed
```

Answer (score 2):

`SYMB` is the result of the `unnest()`, so that is what you want to trim:

```
select . . . , trim(symb)
```